# Display two different columns from two different tables with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, select

I want to display the values of two different tables, and two different columns from that table, sorted in ascending order.

How can I do that?

I use this to display values of two tables, but stuck in sorting by ascending order:

```
select 
  distinct varWinePrice 
from 
  tbl_wines 
union 
select 
  distinct varPrice 
from 
  tbl_price
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If column names are different then sorting should be done using the column of the first subselect:

```
select distinct varWinePrice 
from `tbl_wines` 
union 
select distinct varPrice 
from tbl_price
order by varWinePrice
```

Comment: how it is sorting the another column also can you pls explain?

Comment: @jeni After the process of UNION there is only one column made of two columns. The name of this newly created column is the same as the name of the column in the first subselect.

Comment: @Karolis - Isn't the DISTINCT in each query unnecessary as the UNION will remove duplicates? Not sure if performance is better one way or the other.

Comment: @Tony Yes it's unnecessary. But the performance in my opinion may differ depending on particular data and indexes.

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct varWinePrice as x from tbl_wines union
select distinct varPrice as x from tbl_price
order by x asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

you may nest your UNION select into outer select

```
select
  pr.price
from (
  select 
    distinct varWinePrice 
  from 
    tbl_wines 
  union 
  select 
    distinct varPrice 
  from 
    tbl_price
) pr
order by
  pr.price
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary table to use order by syntax:
1) Create  temporary table
2) Fill the temporary table with records
3) get the rows from temporary table by applying order by clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Price
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT varWinePrice AS Price FROM tbl_wines 
       UNION
       SELECT distinct varPrice AS Price FROM tbl_price
     )
ORDER BY Price
```