# MYSQL help getting latest post or reply

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables below forum_reply and forum_post .
How can i get the latest post or reply which ever is the latest for matching forum_category_id of say 1.
I need to retrieve the date , the author and the forum_(post or reply)_id , forum_category_id

```
forum_post_id   int(11) No  Primary NULL    auto_increment
    forum_category_id   int(11) No  None    NULL    
    forum_post_title    varchar(255)    No  None    NULL    
    forum_post_description  mediumtext  No  None    NULL    
    customer_id int(11) No  None    0   
    forum_post_author   varchar(64) No  None    NULL    
    forum_post_email    varchar(128)    No  None    NULL    
    is_lock tinyint(1)  No  None    0   
    is_stick    tinyint(1)  No  None    0   
    is_notify   tinyint(1)  No  None    0   
    status  tinyint(1)  No  None    0   
    view    int(8)  No  None    0   
    post_added  datetime    No  None    0000-00-00 00:00:00

post_rate   int(8)  No  None    0   
    ip  varchar(32) No  None    NULL    
    post_icon   varchar(128)    No  None    default.png
```

AND

```
    forum_reply_id  int(11) No  Primary NULL    auto_increment
    forum_post_id   int(11) No  None    NULL    
    forum_category_id   int(11) No  None    NULL    
    forum_reply_description mediumtext  No  None    NULL    
    customer_id int(11) No  None    0   
    forum_reply_author  varchar(255)    No  None    NULL    
    forum_reply_email   varchar(128)    No  None    NULL    
    is_notify   tinyint(1)  No  None    0   
    status  tinyint(1)  No  None    0   
    reply_added datetime    No  None    0000-00-00 00:00:00 
    reply_rate  int(8)  No  None    0   
    ip  varchar(32) No  None    NULL    
    reply_icon  varchar(128)    No  None    default.png
```

Comment: what have you tried ? and what is your programming language or do you mean you want to know the SQL ?

Comment: Would be nice a [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com) for a quickly and better answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just a little tip for the future: posting the real `CREATE TABLE` statements requires the same effort than posting the info in tabular data and allows others to easily load stuff in their local `test` database.

Comment: Sorry i need to get the latest post based on the forum_category_id from either the table forum_reply or forum_post which ever is the newest and i need the author the date and the post_id or reply_id

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to combine the two tables in a `SELECT` statement should help you:

```
SELECT
    forum_post_author,
    post_added,
    forum_post_id,
    forum_category_id,
    'post' as type
FROM
    forum_post
WHERE
    forum_category_id = 1

UNION
SELECT
    forum_reply_author,
    reply_added,
    forum_reply_id,
    forum_category_id,
    'reply' as type
FROM
    forum_reply
WHERE
    forum_category_id = 1

ORDER BY
    post_added DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87d3f/1/0)

Comment: After testing both this is the better query as it gives me a type field telling me if it was a reply or post. Thanx guys for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_added, forum_post_author, forum_post_id, forum_category_id 
FROM forum_post WHERE forum_category_id = 1 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT reply_added, forum_reply_author, forum_reply_id, forum_category_id 
FROM forum_reply WHERE forum_category_id = 1 
ORDER BY post_added DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you're trying to do what I think you're doing this should do it I think (but I'm not that pro either).

More info on this here: 
[Display two different columns from two different tables with ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828369/display-two-different-columns-from-two-different-tables-with-order-by)

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, forgot that bit. Edited the post to reflect the correct query